# How do I add vcardfile in the composer sheet of an iPhone application

Tags: iphone, email, attachment, vcf-vcard

in the mail sheet im able to add images but where as im not able to attach vcard file

```
MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[picker addAttachmentData:ExportVCF mimeType:@"text/x-vcard" 
                           fileName:@ "JOHNSMITH.vcf"];
```

but when i send a mail im not getting the attachment

Comment: How'd you create a vcf file? Would appreciate a heads-up

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation for MFMailCompserViewController:

> The MIME type of the specified data. (For example, the MIME type for a JPEG image is
>   image/jpeg.) For a list of valid MIME types, see
>   http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/. This parameter must not be nil.

If you look at the link, you can see all the valid MIME types, and `text/x-vcard` is not listed. I think this means that the Mail composer view controller isn't going to allow you attach a a file with an invalid (in it's opinion) MIME type.

Comment: can anyone tel me what is the valid mime type for vcard

Comment: i also tried multipart/alternative,
application/vcf
it did not attach the vcard in mail whenn send

Comment: The only one I could find was http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/vnd.groove-vcard which was registered by an application called Groove. It may work, it may not work. I'm not sure if this is the same kind of vcard you're referring to or if it just happens to have the same name...

Answer (score 1):

As per the updates in MIME Types on 2014-08-04

> http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml

vcard `text/vcard`format will allow you to attach vcf-vcard file.

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mailer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
mailer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[mailer setSubject:@"vCard"];
[mailer addAttachmentData:data mimeType:@"text/vcard" fileName:@"File.vcf"];
[self presentModalViewController:mailer animated:YES];
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Update based on [Wikipedia vCard page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard):

The standard Internet media type for a vCard (often referred to as its mime type) is:

```
text/vcard
```

As of version 4.0 specification, other media types known to have been used previously are now deprecated, including:

```
text/x-vcard
text/directory;profile=vCard
text/directory
```